# Accessing input channels in a control system

Tags: matlab

I synthesize an H<sub>infinity</sub> controller for a 2x2 plant named `G` and build a closed loop system in the MATLAB Editor. I want to give the first input channel an input, for example a pulse signal, and to give the second input channel another pulse signal with a delay. How can I reach the input channels and do that?

```
[k,cl,Gam,Info]=mixsyn(G,w1,w2,w3);
L=series(k1,G);          % Open loop tf
sys=feedback(L,eye(2));  % building feedback 
G.u='u';
G.y='y';
k2.u='e';
k2.y='u';
sum=sumblk('e=r-y',2);
T=connect(k2,G,sum,'r','y');
```

Comment: I hope you mean a "closed **loop** system"?

Comment: Maybe if you explained your code a bit more we could help. I think this is a question about MATLAB syntax, but without knowing anything about the Control System Toolbox, it's hard to understand what you are trying to do.